# How to use screen rotation in Awesome WM configuration?

Tags: configuration, awesome, xrandr

I'm using an [`xrandr` script](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.screenlayout/right-tack.sh) to set screen size and rotation. In this case one screen is in landscape mode and the other is rotated. How can I detect this rotation in the [Awesome WM configuration](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.config/awesome/rc.lua)?

The goal is to set the tag layout so that the windows are divided along the short axis of the screen. That is, a tag which uses `awful.layout.suit.tile` in landscape mode would use `awful.layout.suit.tile.bottom` in portrait mode. That is, rather than this:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today this is rather easy. Assuming you have the following layouts defined in your `rc.lua`:

```
awful.layout.layouts = {
    awful.layout.suit.tile,
    awful.layout.suit.tile.bottom,
}
```

With `awful.screen.connect_for_each_screen(func)` you can call a function for each existing and created-in-the-future screen. It is very likely you have such a call in your `rc.lua` already (for example to set the wallpaper or create tags). Depending on your configuration you need something like this:

```
awful.screen.connect_for_each_screen(function(s)
    if s.geometry.width >= s.geometry.height then
      awful.tag({ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0" }, s, awful.layout.layouts[1])
    else
      awful.tag({ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0" }, s, awful.layout.layouts[2])
    end
  end)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering a five year old question! Yes, it's been bugging me all this time, and yes, your solution worked. [Actual implementation](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/tilde/commit/a4a0029a0a132d392cf12b9208a5c5509f73b148)

Comment: Updated [url](https://gitlab.com/engmark/tilde/-/commit/a4a0029a0a132d392cf12b9208a5c5509f73b148) for implementation.